# Question regarding inverse of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

If $u_1,....u_n$ are orthonormal Eigen vectors of a n dimensional space, and I define a matrix

$A=[u_1.....u_n]$ where column $j$ equals $u_j$, then clearly if $B =$  $transpose(A)$ then $BA=I$

Is it also true that $AB=I$ so that $A$ and $B$ are inverses of each other?

More generally, if two matrices $C,D$ are such that $CD=I$ this does not necessarily mean that $DC =I$ correct?

Comment: For square matrices $A$ and $B$, it is true that $AB=I$ implies $BA=I$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the dimension of the matrices. For example, if $A = \matrix{(1&-1)}$ and $B = \left(\matrix{1\\0}\right)$, then $AB = 1 = I_1$ but $BA \neq I.$